# Incorrect number of dimensions using vif function

Tags: r

I am trying to run the vif function (lowercase letters) in rstudio using the data frame below but I keep getting an error stating

> Error in y[, i] : incorrect number of dimensions

What am I doing wrong? Why is the vif function giving me the error?

What I have already tried is the code below.

```
library(usdm) # needed for vif function
x1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
x2 <- c(6,7,8,9,10)
x3 <- c(11,12,13,14,15)
y <- c(44,55,66,77,88)
dataFrame = data.frame(x1,x2,x3,y)
vif(dataFrame)
```

The expected results should be a table such as,

```
  Variables            VIF
1        x1       9.294002
2        x2       3.324287
3        x3       5.665959
4         Y      12.011500
```

Note: in this case all the numbers in the VIF column are just picked at random by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I tracked down this error to the following line of code within the `usdm:::.vif` function (more on how I did this later, if you're interested):

```
lm(y[, i] ~ ., data = y[-i])
```

Here, `y` is your `dataFrame` object, and `i` is a column index from your `dataFrame`.... so if you did something like the following, you will encounter the same error:

```
y = dataFrame
i = 1
lm(y[, i] ~ ., data = y[-i])
```

I believe the issue here is the `.vif` function is naming your object (`dataFrame`) as `y` and your data also has a variable named `y`.

To get past this, you can just re-name the variable `y` in your data frame to something else, say `z`:

```
library(usdm) # needed for vif function
x1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
x2 <- c(6,7,8,9,10)
x3 <- c(11,12,13,14,15)
z <- c(44,55,66,77,88)
dataFrame = data.frame(x1,x2,x3,z)
vif(dataFrame)
```

In case you're interested:

To track down this error, I initially just typed the `vif` function in the console to look at the code. However, it is a generic function. I followed [How can I view the source code for a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function) and by doing:

```
showMethods("vif")
getMethod("vif", "data.frame")
```

I was able to see the code for said function. Within the code that is revealed, you will see a point where the following line is executed:

```
v <- .vif(x)
```

I then ran `debugonce(usdm:::.vif)` in the console, and ran your code. This allowed me to step into the function to find the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it to work using your explanation by doing the following:   library(usdm) # needed for vif function
x1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
x2 <- c(6,7,8,9,10)
x3 <- c(11,12,13,14,15)
z <- c(44,55,66,77,88) y1 <- z
# put all the variables above into a data frame so we can run vif()

dataset <- CH06PR12
dataset <- dataset[c("x1","x2","x3")]
dataset$cases1 <- y1 # append y1 to the data set with column name "cases1"

vif(dataset)

Comment: Also, thank you for providing information about the source code so I know how the vif function works 'under the hood' in R.